# Gulp generates a throw Error when using SASS instead of SCSS

Tags: css, wordpress, automation, sass, gulp

I am working off of a boilerplate WordPress theme built with a gulp workflow. CSS is written using SCSS, I find SASS more intuitive and easier to work with. However when I change the gulp tasks to focus on SASS and not SCSS files I get this error whenever I run the task:

```
unlock git:(master) ✗ gulp styles
[11:37:25] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/gulpfile.js
[11:37:25] Starting 'styles'...
[11:37:25] Finished 'styles' after 20 ms
buffer.js:169
  throw new TypeError('must start with number, buffer, array or string');
  ^

TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string
    at fromObject (buffer.js:169:9)
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:62:10)
    at Transform.transform [as _transform] (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/index.js:145:21)
    at Transform._read (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at Transform._write (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at Transform.Writable.write (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at write (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-filter/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-filter/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-filter/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:664:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at emitReadable_ (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-filter/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:448:10)
    at emitReadable (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-filter/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:444:5)
    at readableAddChunk (/Users/tijaniogunlende/Desktop/unlockafrica/wordpress/wp-content/themes/unlock/node_modules/gulp-filter/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:187:9)
```

When I change the files back to the SCSS source everything works fine. 
I know its something small but haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not screenshot code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but I got it from not having any style sheets. So basically I had no styling, and then it tried to put all that nothing into one file. I fixed mine by just creating a one file and putting some comments in it so that it would at least have some content to work with.

I don't know how helpful this is, but here it is anyway.

Comment: Funny enough, I found a workaround by running my sass compilation though codekit instead of using the CLI to compile. Not an ultimate solution but I was able to compile to css and then push the theme to a server after building.